# Angularjs: Issue keeping model and url in sync

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular for a portion of a page on a standard site (Not a single page app)

I have the following js and html code:

JS

```
App.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',
    function($scope, $location) {
        $scope.fruit = 'Apple';

        $scope.selectFruit = function(fruit) {
            $scope.fruit = fruit;
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="cherry" href="#cherry" ng-click="selectFruit('cherry')">Cherry</a></li>
    <li><a id="banana" href="#banana" ng-click="selectFruit('banana')">Banana</a></li>
    <li><a id="grape"  href="#grape"  ng-click="selectFruit('grape')">Grape</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I click the links in this order, cherry -> banana -> grape, the url will change accordingly
with the #{fruit} in the url as expected.

When I click the browser's back button once, the url will change in the reverse order, in this case, from #grape to #banana

However, the value of $scope.fruit will still be grape.

How can I update the value of $scope.fruit to match the url (#banana) the 'angular way'? Should i be listening to changes on the $location (seems like hack) or have I just architected the entire thing incorrectly?

Comment: you didnt put the code where you change the location,you didnt write the relevant part of the code that would help us correct that bug,nor the routerProvider configuration.

Comment: @mpm, the location isn't being changed programatically.  It's being injected for another unrelated reason and I've left that part out.